# Job schedular stops when closing app in MIUI with Oreo 8.1

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler, miui

I am trying to start background service in app using job schedular but it stops when i close app in MIUI with Oreo 8.1.It works perfectly in other phones but not with MIUI.Please help if anyone have solution.

Thank you

Comment: MIUI requires user to explicitly enable autostart in application settings.

Comment: @Pawel - i have allowed all permissions and function but its not working